# lerpColor() / fill() throwing NullPointerException with Processing

Tags: colors, processing

This is the code for a class:

```
class Circle extends PApplet {
  //var declarations

  Circle(int duration, int from, int to, PApplet parent, int x, int y, int length, int height){
    this.ani = new Tween(parent, 1.3f, Tween.SECONDS, Shaper.QUADRATIC);
    Class s = Shaper.QUADRATIC;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.len = length;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  void update(){
    int c = lerpColor(this.from, this.to, this.ani.position(), RGB);

    fill(c);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.len, this.height);
  }
}
```

When I run `update()` on a properly seeded version of `Circle` (see below example), I get this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at processing.core.PApplet.fill(PApplet.java:13540)
at ellipses.Circle.update(Ellipses.java:85)
at ellipses.Ellipses.draw(Ellipses.java:39)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2128)
at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:190)
at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2006)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

It tells me that inside `fill()`, something is null when it shouldn't be. I would at first assume the value passed to `fill()` is somehow wrong. The value to `fill()` comes from `lerpColor()`, so presumably I've used `lerpColor()` wrongly.

My instance of `Circle` looks like this:

```
int c1 = color(45, 210, 240);
int c2 = color(135, 130, 195);

cir = new Circle(1, c1, c2, this, 100, 200, 140, 140);
cir.update();
```

**So how can I use `fill()`/`lerpColor` correctly?**

(BTW, I'm using processing in eclipse with proclipsing.)

Comment: @Petros is right -- you shouldn't extend PApplet unless this is your main class.  It seems it's not, since you're calling `new Circle()` from elsewhere.  That said, `c` cannot be `null`, as `null` is not a valid value for `int` in Java.  Something else must be going on here.  Have you tried `println(c)`?  What value do you get?

Comment: @ericsoco, I've since checked to check the c has a correct value, and it was. As I've said on Petros' answer, calling `fill()` on the parent applet worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all I am not entirely sure why would you need to extend the PApplet from a class that does not seem to be one of your windows, but i digress.

If I understand what you are trying to do, the problem lies with the fill function and not with lerpColor. If you are trying to call the fill function of your main PApplet and this Circle class is not it, then you need to tell it on which PApplet to call it. i.e. the parent that you already send in. I'd do something like this.

```
class Circle extends PApplet {
  //var declarations
  Tween ani;
  int from, to, x, y, len, heightz;

  PApplet parr; // prepare to accept the parent instance

  Circle(int duration, int from, int to, PApplet parent, int x, int y, int length, int height) {
    this.ani = new Tween(parent, 1.3f, Tween.SECONDS, Shaper.QUADRATIC);
    Class s = Shaper.QUADRATIC;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.len = length;
    this.heightz = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    parr = parent; // store the parent instance
  }
  void update() {
    color c = lerpColor(this.from, this.to, this.ani.position(), RGB);
    parr.fill(c); // call fill on the parent
    parr.ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.len, this.height); // this one obviously suffers from the same problem...
  }
```

I hope this helps!
pk

Comment: I was extending PApplet becuase I needed to extend it to be able to refernce `fill()`. I was using the wrong one evidently, becuase calling it on the parent PApplet worked. Thanks.